# docker: permissions error for mounted volume

Tags: docker

I've built a docker image from a Dockerfile available on Github. I'm running it with the recommended command:

```
docker run -i --rm -v </my/local/path>:</path_inside_container>:ro -v </another/local/path>:</another_path_inside_container>:ro <image_name> <...more arguments...>
```

However, I immediately get the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/path_inside_container\": permission denied": unknown.
```

I've looked online for a solution, but most posts involve *restricting* the permissions of mounted volumes. The closest I have found is [this](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Permission-Denied-quot-exec-entrypoint-sh-quot/td-p/31249), where the problem was with a script. It was solved by setting execute permissions for the script with chmod. My case is different, but I tried setting the permissions of the local directory to '777' with chmod just in case; this did not work. The problem is with the directory created *inside* the container.

If anyone has a suggestion regarding what could be wrong, or can point me to resources that explain where/how the permissions for mounted volumes *inside* containers are set, it would be a big help. Thank you!

Comment: which image are you using

Comment: you are running just like this 
docker run -i --rm -v </my/local/path>:</path_inside_container>:ro -v </another/local/path>:</another_path_inside_container>:ro <image_name> <...more arguments...>